# VS2017 cordova iOS build fails with no error code

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-cordova

When trying to build a cordova app from visual studio 2017 for iOS on a Mac using remoteserver, the build fails and no reason for the failure is provided.

The build is done following the procedure in
[Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova: iOS Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/first-steps/ios-guide) using remoteserver in non-secure mode.

The remoteserver, jnode and xcode have been updated on the Mac. The same application was built previously from VS2015 with a similar setup.

The last few entries in the VS output window are:

```
Wrote out iOS Bundle Identifier "com.bytebloc.sked" and iOS Bundle Version "2.1" to /Users/ccs/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/600/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/#TestApp#/#TestApp#-Info.plist
Set TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY to "1,2".
iOS Product Name has not changed (still "#TestApp#")
Updating icons at platforms/ios/#TestApp#/Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/
Updating splash screens at platforms/ios/#TestApp#/Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/
Prepared iOS project successfully
Executing script found in config.xml for hook "after_prepare": hooks/xcode8.js
Checking config.xml for saved plugins that haven't been added to the project
Saving ios@4.2.0 into platforms.json
No scripts found for hook "after_platform_add".
Failed to build app for buildNumber 600:
```

The remoteserver window shows the following entries:

```
taco-remote-multiplexer downloaded and installed.
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/ccs/.taco_home/node_modules/taco-remote-multiplexer/latest/node_modules/taco-remote-multiplexer/tacoRemoteMultiplexer.js'
Build will be executed under: /Users/ccs/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/600
Saving build request payload to : /Users/ccs/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/600
Saved uploaded build to /Users/ccs/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/600/upload_600.tgz
POST /cordova/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=6.3.1&cfg=release&options=--device 202 1348.564 ms - 629
GET /cordova/build/tasks/600 200 0.970 ms - 629
Extracted app contents from uploaded build request to /Users/ccs/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/600/cordovaApp. Requesting build.
Taking 600 as current build
GET /cordova/build/tasks/600 200 1.428 ms - 687
Done with current build. Checking for next build in queue.
```

Based on [this discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/remotebuild/issues/8), it does not appear that the ENOENT error is the source of the issue.

Additionally, running file build.xcconfig for the build directly on the Mac from directory /cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build results in the application being compiled and built successfully.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to insist that is important to:

install latest version on windows : npm install -g cordova
configure VS to use cordova 7.0.0 (on config.xml, in the platforms tab. If you don't see it, just change taco.json to 7.0.0)
install latest cordova on mac : npm install -g cordova
install on mac the latest version of ios-deploy : npm install ios-deploy
remove the folder ~/.taco-home/node_modules/
install the latest remotebuild on mac : npm install remotebuild (it should be 2.1.3).

Comment: Still does not work. However, the error has changed. VS reports: Remotebuild requires your projects to use cordova-ios 4.3.0 or greater with XCode 8.3. Please update your cordova-ios version.

Comment: update cordova on windows and in visual studio change in config.xml to cordova 7.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Updating cordova on my mac solved my issue.

Comment: I to update both cordova and the ios within cordova:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44321757/how-to-update-cordova-ios-version-in-visual-studio-2015-cordova-project