# how to update cordova-ios version in visual studio 2015 cordova project?

Tags: visual-studio, cordova

I'm developing ios app using cordova template in visual studio 2015.
I have configured mac book as described in this link .https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/ios-guide/#run-your-app-in-an-ios-simulator.
Installed xcode version is 8.3.
when i try to run app in an ios simulator , getting following error. so, how to fix this, please help .thanks.

Error: Remote build error from the build server Build failed with error Remotebuild requires your projects to use cordova-ios 4.3.0 or greater with XCode 8.3. Please update your cordova-ios version.

Answer (score 2):

From [this link](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html) you can see how to update cordova:

```
npm update -g cordova
```

On [next link](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/upgrade.html) you can find instructions for ios cordova update. Basically its just removing ios platform and adding it back again for projects built with Cordova 4.x version:

```
cordova platform rm ios
cordova platform add ios
```

For older versions use:

```
cordova platform update ios
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. but is not this solution for cordova CLI version? . I'm developing my app using visual studio 2015 cordova tools. so how can i update cordova-ios version using visual studio 2015?

Comment: I am not sure about sure this can be done via VS. It is really simple to do it via CLI, so i suggest you try it.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2015 was forcing the 4.1.1 version for cordova-ios.

This worked for me on the command line:

```
cordova platform add ios@4.3.1
```

[cordova-ios 4.3.1](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2016/12/02/ios-release.html)

**Note:** And i deleted the "bld" folder from the cordova project root.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me in Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition.

1) Delete the platforms / ios folder in the root folder of your project

2) In the platforms folder, edit the platforms.json file manually with the version you want, in my case it was:

```
{
"android": "5.2.1",
"ios": "4.3.0"
}
```

3) Update your config.xml file in your project like so:

```
  <engine name="ios" spec="4.3.0" />
```

4) Run your project.